# kubernetes apps avalaible on localhost

Tags: kubernetes, localhost

I have local  and dockerized apps which are working excelent on localhost : java backend at 8080, angular at 4200, activemq at 8161, and postgres on 5432
Now,I am trying also to kubernetize apps to make them work on localhosts.
As far as I know kubernetes provides random Ip on clusters, what should  I do do make them work on localhosts to listen to each other ? Is there any way to make them automatically start at those localhosts instead of using port forwariding for each service ?
Every service and deployment has similiar structure :

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: backend
spec:
selector:
app: backend
type: LoadBalancer
ports:
- protocol: 8080
port: 8080
targetPort: 8080

Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
name: backend
labels:
app: backend
spec:
replicas: 3
selector:
matchLabels:
app: backend
template:
metadata:
labels:
app: backend
spec:
containers:
- name: backend
image: 
ports:
- containerPort: 8080

Tried port-forwarding, works, but requires lot of manual work ( open few new powershell windows and then do manual port forwarding)

Answer (score 1):

In the kubernetes eco system apps talk to each other through their services.
If they are in the same namespace they can directly go to the service name of not they need to specify the full name which includes the namespace name:
my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster-domain.example

Comment: dont understand as i am beginner in kubernetes;  In local and dockerized version angular instantly fetch data exposed by backend. In kubernetes I didn't provide any namespaces. In kubernetes version angular works and random ip, backend on different ip, and they dont fetch data between them

Comment: In kubernetes each pod has a service if you deployed it with a service. Other pods use this service to communicate to this pod. Maybe abit similar like network in docker
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, find a way to do it automaticaly with port - forwarding, with simply running 1 script
I have wrote a .bat script with these steps:

1. kubernetes run all deployments file
2. kubernetes run all services file
3. 15 second timeout to give time to change pod state from pending to running
4. { do port forwarding for each service. Every forwarding is in new powershell windows without exiting }